# Is there a way url redirect internally to particular service based on context path?

Tags: kubernetes, multi-tenant, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

There are multiple same pods running in one cluster but different namespaces. This is the web application running in Kubernetes. I have the URL `<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/context/abc/def/.....`. I want to redirect to particular service based on the context. Is there a way i can achieve it using ingress controller ? Or Is there any way i can achieve it using different ports through ingress ?

My web application works fine if the URL is `<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/abc/def/.....`. Since i have to access the different pods using the same URL, I am adding context to it. Do we have any other way to achieve this use case ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with  `rewrite-target`. In example below i used  `<HOSTNAME>`  value of  `rewrite.bar.com`  and  `<PORT>`  with value  `80`.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: context-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /context1(/|$)(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: context-service2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /context2(/|$)(.*)
```

For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites:

`rewrite.bar.com/context1`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/` for context 1 service.

`rewrite.bar.com/context2`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/` for context 2 service.

`rewrite.bar.com/context1/new`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/new` for context 1 service.

`rewrite.bar.com/context2/new`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/new` for context 2 service.

Comment: I have edited my answer to address multiple backend services and fixed code block formatting.

Comment: If my url contains host:port/context1/new/abc/def/, will this work

Comment: Yes, but You have to remember to have correct `servicePort` and `host` matching with the host and port You used. So for example `http://example.com:80/context1/new/abc/def/` will redirect to  `http://example.com:80/new/abc/def/` on service that matches selector for context1 criteria on `host` example.com and `targetPort` 80.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. It is not redirecting to the rewrite.bar.com/new

Answer (score 0):

You can manage how the traffic is pointed to the correct service by using the rules configuration of the ingress, here is a simple example from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /abc
        backend:
          serviceName: abc-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /context
        backend:
          serviceName: context-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: I can do that. But my url is working without context. If i am adding the context my api is not working. Because my rest end point got changed. Is there any way we can without adding any context. I just want to achieve multitenancy using namespace separation.