# Deploy service at subpath without redirect in Kubernetes

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want to have one base url with different services deployed at different subpath in my Kubernetes cluster like this:

```
https://base.url/service-a   # -> service-a
https://base.url/service-b   # -> service-b
# ...
```

But I don't want the service to know about its prefix. I would like to avoid hardcoding the `/serivce-*` prefix in each service.

So **internally** I need all `/service-a/*` routes to map to `/*`. While externally the url should stay the same. So I **do not want** to be redirected from `https://base.url/service-a/subpath` to `https://base.url/subpath`.

My first thought was, that this should work:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main
  namespace: app-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"    
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - base.url
    secretName: some-secret
  rules:
  - host: base.url/service-a
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service-a
            port:
              number: 8080
  # ... other services as different hosts
```

But it does not. It fails with `Invalid value: "base.url/service-a": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.'`. Seems like the `spec.rules[*].host` is not allowed to contain path elements.

I also tried using the `nginx-ingress` controller with the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation as suggested in multiple questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977643/is-there-a-way-url-redirect-internally-to-particular-service-based-on-context-pa) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923298/remove-routing-path-from-kubernetes-ingress):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main
  namespace: app-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"   
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - base.url
    secretName: some-secret
  rules:
  - host: base.url
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /service-a(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service-a
            port:
              number: 8080
      # ... other services as different paths
```

If I use postman or the browser and make a request to `https://base.url/service-a/subpath` I am redirected to `https://base.url/subpath` which returns a `404` because this is not a valid endpoint on my cluster.

I simply want to remove the prefix `/service-a` for **internal routing**.

NOTE: I also want to avoid hosting the services in subdomains like `service-a.base.url` because this would make my setup more complicated in regards to CORS.

Comment: Your second example looks good.
In my opinion, a request to `https://base.url/service-a/subpath` should go to `service-a -> /subpath`.
Do you have `/subpath` configured for `service-a` ?

Comment: Obviously I do. When printing the logs via `kubectl logs <pod-name>` nothing is logged so the request never reaches the service. When using `- path: /` (without the `/service-a` prefix) and removing the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` line the request succeeds and it is also visible in `kubectl logs <pod-name>`. Interestingly using `- path: /service-a` and `*/rewrite-target: /` results in a log with `/` in the logs for any request to `/service-a/*`.

Comment: Are you using [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) or [nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) ?

Comment: I am following this guide: https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/ingress/ so I guess `kubernetes/ingress-nginx`.

Comment: Check the Ingress Controller logs, they should give you information on where the `https://base.url/service-a/subpath` request goes.

Comment: The logs show two entries:
`"GET /service-a/subpath HTTP/1.1" 301 45 "http://base.url/service-a/subpth" [...] [service-a-8080]`,
`"GET /subpath HTTP/1.1" 404 146 "https://base.url/subpath" [...] [upstream-default-backend]`.
And as I mentioned above the latter does not exist, thats why its handled by the default backend internally.

Comment: Can you provide your `service-a` configuration ?
Is it possible for you to query directly this Pod using `kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -n app-namespace -- curl localhost/subpath` or any similar command ?